# PHP: Database not selected

Tags: php, sql, database-connection

I'm failing to understand why the function to connect to the database is not working, I have triple checked if there are any mistakes in the variables.

Using mysql_error function on class.php at line 12 I get the following error:

```
No database selected
```

class.php

```
 <?php

class blog {
    private $host;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $db;
    private $link;

    public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $db){
    $this->link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);
    mysql_select_db($this->db, $this->link) or die (mysql_error());

    }

    function get_content(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM content";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        echo '<h1>'.$row['title'].'</h1>';
        echo '<p>'.$row['body'].'</p>';
        }
    }
}// End of Class
?>
```

index.php

```
  <?php include 'includes/class.php' ?>
<?php


//Setup Connection
$obj = new blog('localhost', 'root', '', 'blog');

//Connect to DB

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" mce_href="styles1.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Mi Blog</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="page-wrap">
    <?php $obj->get_content() ?>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using `$this->db` but never setting it. Try this:

```
public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $db){
    $this->db = $db;
    $this->link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);
    mysql_select_db($this->db, $this->link) or die (mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You are failing to set `$this->db`.

Answer (score 4):

First of all

```
mysql_select_db($this->db, $this->link) or die (mysql_error());
```

should be:

```
mysql_select_db($db, $this->link) or die (mysql_error());
```

and

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);
```

should be

```
$res = mysql_query($sql, $this->link);
```